# How can I define Closure as action for Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am using this down code but xCode doesn't compile even due to:
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
    let action: () -> Void = { stringOfText = "updated!" }       // <<: Here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(stringOfText)
            .padding()
        
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text("update")
        })
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it as a function:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    func action() {
        self.stringOfText = "updated!"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(stringOfText)
            .padding()
        
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text("update")
        })
        
    }
}
```

Related SO about capturing `self` during init (which is what your original code is doing by defining a closure in a property like that): [Referencing self in super.init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996228/referencing-self-in-super-init) In short, it's a complicated thing, and requires tricky thinking to avoid. But, luckily something like just defining it as a function here doesn't seem to have any downside.

Comment: But what if we want use closures? as we can see on Button initializer method, we can define a closure like: **() -> Void** and IMHO I know the reason of error I just wanted make it to work

Comment: Check out the link I posted -- it's different because it's in the initializer.